# How to generate options based on values in an array in flutter pltform action sheet?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using flutter [platform action sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/platform_action_sheet#-readme-tab-) to get input from the user, but the number of options to choose from is not always the same, i wanted to know if there is any way to show options based on the values in an array.

```
    return Center(
    child: FlatButton(
    color: Colors.blue,
    onPressed: () => PlatformActionSheet().displaySheet(
    context: context,
    title: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
      ],
    ),
    message: Text("Choose a Region"),
    actions: [
       I want the options to be here
      ActionSheetAction(
        text: "Cancel",
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        isCancel: true,
        defaultAction: true,
      )
    ])));
```

The code above is the code that I'm using, and i want to put the options above the cancel button.help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like the following code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:platform_action_sheet/platform_action_sheet.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Example App',
      home: new Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var op = ["Option 1", "Option 2"];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Example App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () => PlatformActionSheet().displaySheet(
              context: context,
              title: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Hello Mum"),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.beach_access,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: 36.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              message: Text("I'm in London"),
              actions: op.map((e) => ActionSheetAction(
                text: e,
                onPressed: () => doSomething(e),
                hasArrow: true,
              )).toList()),
          child: Text(
            'Display ActionSheet',
            textScaleFactor: 1.2,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  doSomething(String e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

You can map the actions based on the string sent as a parameter in `doSomething()`

Comment: it says  Error: A value of type 'List<ActionSheetAction>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ActionSheetAction'.

Comment: Check the updated answer. I added the complete code.